# Asynchronous message handling with Akka's Actors

Tags: scala, akka, actor

In my project I'm using Akka's Actors. By definition Actors are thread-safe, which means that in the Actor's *receive* method

```
def receive = {
    case msg =>
        // some logic here
}
```

only one thread at a time processes the commented piece of code. However, things are starting to get more complicated when this code is asynchronous:

```
def receive = {
    case msg =>
        Future {
            // some logic here
        }
}
```

If I understand this correctly, in this case only the Future construct will be synchronized, so to speak, and not the logic **inside** the Future.

Of course I may block the Future:

```
def receive = {
    case msg =>
        val future = Future {
            // some logic here
        }
        Await.result(future, 10.seconds)
}
```

which solves the problem, but I think we all should agree that this is hardly an acceptable solution.

So this is my question: how can I retain the thread-safe nature of actors in case of asynchronous computing **without** blocking Scala's Futures?

Comment: just add a callback to the Future as described in http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html . Callback should send a message to this or another actor.

Answer (score 6):

> How can I retain the thread-safe nature of actors in case of
>   asynchronous computing without block Scalas `Future`?

This assumption is only true if you modify the internal state of the actor inside the `Future` which seems to be a design smell in the first place. Use the future for computation only by creating a *copy* of the data and pipe to result of the computation to the actor using `pipeTo`. Once the actor receives the result of the computation you can safely operate on it:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

case class ComputationResult(s: String)

def receive = {
  case ComputationResult(s) => // modify internal state here
  case msg =>
    Future {
       // Compute here, don't modify state
       ComputationResult("finished computing")
    }.pipeTo(self)
}
```

Comment: Actually the logic inside the Future deals with Mongo database. We are using ReactiveMongo, which is asynchronous (hence the described issue). So I have to make sure the next message is processed only after the previous one has been processed, which means that the asynchronous call to the database should have already been resolved.

Comment: @SergeyVolkov If that is the issue then this isn't related to Akka actors at all, it's about allowing your database to finish its transaction before processing the next one. In that case, you can implement a blocking queue logic which only ever processes the next item in the queue upon completion.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "resolve" the db query first and then use the result to return a new `Future`. If the db query returns a `Future[A]`, then you can use `flatMap` to operate over `A` and return a new `Future`. Something in the lines of

```
def receive = {
    case msg =>
        val futureResult: Future[Result] = ...
        futureResult.flatMap { result: Result =>
            // ....
            // return a new Future
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the simplest solution here is to turn the actor into a state machine (use AkkaFSM) and do the following:

- dispatch a future for the mongoDB request.
- use the reference to your own actor to commuincate with your actor
- tell the message back from the future.

depending on context you might have to do some more to get a proper response.

But this has the advantage that you process the message with the actor state and you can mutate the actor state as you please as you own the thread.